# SSRS Pie Chart Sorting

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

This may be a simple question for someone.  Can someone show me how to sort or order the slices of pie?  I can sort a bar chart no problem, but there must be something a little different with Pie Charts.

I would like the amounts in order and not scattered around.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's my expression to group.
[image]

Here's my expression to sort.
[image]

and here's where I add the sort options
[image]

My Pie chart.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I continued to work on this and I found that if I sort by the actual dataset field called Total Acct MV instead of the calculated 'Total MV Group' or the calculated field called 'Total MV Sorted' ...then it works fine.